# Sfinae type trait to detect template function doesn't work with std::forward

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, clang, sfinae

I recently tried to make a sfinae type trait to detect if a class contain a particular template static function named `construct`.

I came with this implementation:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct has_template_construct_helper {
private:
    template<typename U, typename... As>
    static std::true_type test(decltype(&U::template construct<As...>)*);

    template<typename...>
    static std::false_type test(...);

public:
    using type = decltype(test<T, Args...>(nullptr));
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
using has_template_construct = typename has_template_construct_helper<T, Args...>::type;
```

I tought that would be okay, and it was. I tried to test my trait with gcc and clang like this:

```
struct TestStruct {
    template<typename... Args>
    static auto construct(int a, double b, Args... args) -> decltype(std::make_tuple(a, b, args...)) {
        return std::make_tuple(1, 2.3, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

// didn't fire! Hurrah!
static_assert(has_template_construct<TestStruct, std::string>::value, "Don't pass the test");
```

It worked for both compiler.

However, as soon as I add forwarding references, clang starts complaining:

```
struct TestStruct {
    template<typename... Args>
    static auto construct(int a, double b, Args&&... args) -> decltype(std::make_tuple(a, b, std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {
        return std::make_tuple(1, 2.3, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

// fires on clang :(
static_assert(has_template_construct<TestStruct, std::string>::value, "Don't pass the test");
```

Here the code snippet on coliru: [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2191d473ef77851), [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b83e8ebcad4bb9a)

My question is: which one between GCC and Clang is wrong, and how can I fix my code to make it work on both compiler?

---

Okay, I tried things, now I'm even more confused. When using `std::declval`, it worked back in clang!

```
struct TestStruct {
    template<typename... Args>
    static auto construct(int a, double b, Args&&... args) -> decltype(std::make_tuple(a, b, std::declval<Args>()...))
    {
        return std::make_tuple(1, 2.3, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

// uh?? Works in clang?
static_assert(has_template_construct<TestStruct, std::string>::value, "Don't pass the test");
```

Comment: Uncomment `test(...)` and see what's the actual error during substitution. This will help.

Comment: What does "doesn't work with std::forward" even mean?  There is no such thing as a type that you can't call std::forward on with compile-time known results.

Comment: I think it's a bug in clang. Adding forwarding reference makes it believe that there is an overload for the construct method and hence it throws out the error.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure why your code is failing in clang++ (or passing in g++). But here is an easier alternative.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

template <typename... T>
using void_t = void;

class Stat {
public:
    template <typename... T>
    static auto construct(int a, double b, T&&... t) ->
      decltype(std::make_tuple(1, 2.3, t...))
    {
      return std::make_tuple(1, 2.3, std::forward<T>(t)...);
    }
};

template <typename Class, typename... Args>
constexpr auto does_have_construct(int)
    -> decltype(&Class::template construct<Args...>, true)
{
    return true;
}

template <typename Class, typename... Args>
constexpr bool does_have_construct(long) { return false; }

class Stat2 {};

int main() {
    static_assert(does_have_construct<Stat, std::string>(0), "Nope!");

    return 0;
}
```

Clang is particularly unhappy when specifying `std::forward<T>` in the decltype of return type deduction. If we remove that, there is no issue. **BUT**, I am not sure now about the correctness of the code!!

In C++14 you could rewrite the `class Stat` as:

```
class Stat {
public:
    template <typename... T>
    static auto construct(int a, double b, T&&... t)
    {
      return std::make_tuple(1, 2.3, std::forward<T>(t)...);
    }
};
```

As you can see, we do not have to take the extra step to fool the compiler in this case.

Comment: hmm... are you sure using forward in the body but not in the return type is supposed to work? Most of the case yes, but if it resolves to a different function, may it cause hidden bugs or compilation errors?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: Yeah, am not that sure of it, thats why I wrote " BUT, I am not sure now about the correctness of the code!!" :) . But, the c++14 way should give you no problem. I really wish someone could expand on the issue with Clang. I couldn't find much on that.